# Inverse Laplace Transform involving irrational powers

Tags: cv.complex-variables, laplace-transform

Could anybody please suggest a reference or a possible solution how to invert the Laplace transform of

$e^{-(s^{\alpha}+\lambda)^{\beta}}$, where $0<\alpha<1$ and $0<\beta<1$.

Comment: F. M. Ragab did some work on inversions of this type. If recalled correctly the solutions are in terms of E-functions and Meijer's G-functions. Of course one could seek forms in terms of Fox's H-function. As to the year and journal I cannot recall.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look for the articles written by the author. Thanks again.. I ll update you....